# Kotlin: Generic function with parameter of type class like Swift with Object.type

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a generic function with a parameter that receives the type of a class for example:

```
class Foo{
    var name = "Foooo"
}

class Liii{
    var name = "Liii"
}
```

Generic function:

```
fun genericFunc(objects: Any, objectType: KClass<*>) {
    print((objects as objectType).name) //This is not exist how to do this?
}
```

And call it like this:

```
val foo = Foo()
genericFun(foo, Foo::class)

val liii = Liii()
genericFun(liii, Liii::class)
```

In swift it exists in this way...

```
func genericFunc(objects: Any, objectType: Object.type) {
    print((objects as objectType).name)
}

let foo = Foo()
genericFun(foo, Foo.self)
```

Comment: That's not legal swift. That coercion isn't guaranteed, so `as` would be invalid, it would need `as?` or `as!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, only Class has a `.name` variable. To be quite honest, I don't see the point of what you're doing here. You can just do `objects::class.java.name` directly if you just want the name. If you want to use KClass, you'll need to use `simpleName` or `qualifiedName`. Class also has `simpleName`, `packageName`, `typeName`, and `canonicalName`. Which also means you need to get the classs. If you absolutely want to cast it, you'll need to re-get the `KClass` or `Class` with respectively `::class` or `::class.java`.

Also, tiny note: I'm not sure how print works in Swift, but in Kotlin and Java, it doesn't print a new line. I'm mentioning this because I know some languages like Python have their `print` function work like `System.out.println` or `println`. However, `print` doesn't automatically create a newline.

---

I actually stumbled over this exact issue yesterday: If I pass a KClass to a function, I can't to `whatever as kClass`, because it's not found. Apparently, you can't do this. `as` and `is` assumes a class name, not an instance of `Class` or `KClass`.

Now, you have two options, both of which use generics.

The first one is still passing the class:

```
fun <T : Any> genericFunc(objects: Any, objectType: KClass<out T>) {
    println(objectType.java.cast(objects))

}
```

If you want to print the name, you have to get the class as I mentioned earlier. This is also slightly pointless, since you can just do this:

```
println(objects::class.java.name)
```

Or if you absolutely have to cast it first (though I recommend checking with `isInstance` first):

```
println(objectType.java.cast(objects)::class.java.name)
```

But if the code isn't the point, let's move on.

The other is using reified types. Here you can use `as`:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> genericFunc(objects: Any) {
    print(objects as T)
}
```

The last one is called differently:

```
genericFunc<SomeClass>(instance);
```

***However;*** this isn't safe. I highly recommend you check types first. For the first one, use `objectType.isInstance(objects)`, for the second you can just use `is`. If you don't, you risk getting a ClassCastException if the type doesn't match.

Also, depending on what you're planning to do with it, you could also use generics entirely:

```
fun <T> genericFunc(objects: T) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Optionally with constraints for the generic type.